# Android java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: android, android-layout

I am loading a webview with a close button and a slide button. When I clic

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" 
    android:layout_marginRight="25dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dip" >
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webac_larger"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</WebView>

<ImageView android:id="@+id/close_btn"         
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"         
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"         
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/close_button"
    android:layout_marginTop="-3dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
    />  

<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/slidebutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/close_btn"
    android:src="@drawable/arrowleft" />
```

I want to resize webview on click of a button.

```
final ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.slidebutton);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
          public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d("MultiWeb", "I have clicked the button");
            RelativeLayout params = ((RelativeLayout )button1.getParent());
             params.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100));
          }
        });
```

I am getting this error. I am using relatice layout and why error says something about frame layout ?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams
```

Comment: @user113215, why don't you make that an answer, so sam can accept it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the [Android Layouts API Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#layout-params), each type of `ViewGroup` has its own `LayoutParams` class that define the size and position for child `View`s.

Instead of creating a brand new instance of one of the `LayoutParams` classes and risking a `ClassCastException`, you can call `getLayoutParams()` on your view to get the current parameter object, modify it as you wish, and call `setLayoutParams()` to apply the updated parameters.